# Blowing up at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $C:=\{y^2=x^3\}$ be a curve in $\mathbb C^2$ and $\pi:X\to \mathbb C^2$ the blowing up of $\mathbb C^2$ at the origin $o:=(0,0)$. The dimension of $X$? Take another blowing $\pi':X'\to X$ at the singular point of the strict transform of $C$. What about $X'$ and the dimension of $X'$?

Comment: Do you know what blowing up is?  Also, the curve $C$ is playing no role in your question as it stands.

Comment: $\Bbb C^2 -o$ is isomorphic to $X - \pi^{-1}(o)$ (where $\pi^{-1}(o)$ is an affine line), and although this is no rigorous proof, it should indicate that $X$ has dimension $2$.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Dear Jesko, this is a great amount of reputation for such a poor (existing) answer ! Hope someone will come up with a better one. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Cantlog: It's not just for this particular answer. It's because you invest your reputation to support other questions, and I have plenty of it to give.

Answer (score 5):

A blowing-up morphism of integral algebraic varieties (more generally of integral schemes) is birational: it is an isomorphism outside of the center we blow-up (under the obvious condition that the center is nowhere dense). As birational algebraic varieties have the same dimension (equal to the transcendental degree of the function fields), blowing-up doesn't change the dimension.

The strict transform of $C$ in $X$ is regular (straightforward computationsn see e.g. a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/)), so the second part of your question is irrelevant.